# How can I install bignum lib for Node.js on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, deployment, heroku, bignum

I get the following error

```
-----> Installing dependencies with npm

   > bignum@0.5.1 install /tmp/build_1xz3suiyqvjwh/node_modules/bignum
   > node-gyp configure build

   sh: node-gyp: not found
   npm ERR! error installing bignum@0.5.1 Error: bignum@0.5.1 install: `node-gyp configure build`
   npm ERR! error installing bignum@0.5.1 `sh "-c" "node-gyp configure build"` failed with 127
   npm ERR! error installing bignum@0.5.1     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-Pi2L/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
   npm ERR! error installing bignum@0.5.1     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
   npm ERR! error installing bignum@0.5.1     at maybeExit (child_process.js:358:16)
   npm ERR! error installing bignum@0.5.1     at Process.onexit (child_process.js:394:5)
   npm ERR! bignum@0.5.1 install: `node-gyp configure build`
   npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp configure build"` failed with 127
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the bignum@0.5.1 install script.
   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bignum package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build
   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls bignum
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-343-ec2
   npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-8eWj/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-Pi2L/cli.js" "install" "--production"
   npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1xz3suiyqvjwh
   npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_1xz3suiyqvjwh/npm-debug.log
   npm not ok
```

!     Failed to install --production dependencies with npm
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app